# How do I restore deleted contacts

Tags: contacts

I've accidentally deleted a number of contacts.  How do I restore them so that they are still members of my organisation?

Answer (score 2):

Short version, assuming you mean they are just in Trash, is

- go to Adv Search,
- tick the box for 'search in trash'
- select the ones to restore
- then under Actions choose 'restore from trash'

Answer (score 0):

There are some instructions at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/undelete/